# Azure AD B2C integration OIDC and SAML

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal-react

I have a React application that is authenticated on AD B2C using OIDC protocol with a custom policy. I have to use custom policy because I need to send an email to the user. Inside this React application I open dashboards from QlikSense and I don't want the user to login again. I've already created another custom policy to authenticate user using SAML protocol on QlikSense, it's working.

My doubt is how can I mix this two custom policy in the same login page? There is no documentation showing how to mix two protocol on the same custom policy.